# Acessing POST field data without a form (REST api) using Django

Tags: python, django, rest, post, django-rest-framework

In the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST), it says:

> HttpRequest.POST
>
> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters, providing that the request contains form data. See the QueryDict documentation below. If you need to access raw or non-form data posted in the request, access this through the HttpRequest.body attribute instead.

However, the server does not respond to a browser (such as using JS frameworks or a form) but instead a REST api sent by an Anroid/iOS application.

If the client sends fields directly in a POST request, how can I read the data? For example, this (Java + Unirest):

```
Unirest.post("/path/to/server")
       .field("field1", "value2")
       .field("field2", "value2");
```

**EDIT:** Can I simply read the data using`response.POST["field1"]`, or will I have to do something with `request.body`?

**EDIT 2:** So I can simply use `request.body` as a dictionary-like object similar to `request.POST`?

Comment: you have all the data in request.body

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understand the field method from Unirest just uses normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data like a HTML form. So you should be able to just use `response.POST["field1"]` like you suggested.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data):

> `request.data` returns the parsed content of the request body. This is
>   similar to the standard `request.POST` and `request.FILES` attributes
>   except that:
>
> - It includes all parsed content, including file and non-file inputs.
> - It supports parsing the content of HTTP methods other than `POST`,    meaning that you can access the content of `PUT` and `PATCH`
>     requests.
> - It supports REST framework's flexible request parsing,    rather than just supporting form data. For example you can handle    incoming
>     `JSON` data in the same way that you handle incoming form data.

---

> Can I simply read the data using `response.POST["field1"]`, or will I
>   have to do something with `request.body`?
>
> So I can simply use `request.body` as a dictionary-like object similar
>   to `request.POST`?

An example - From a `create` method (viewsets):

```
user = dict(
                full_name=request.DATA['full_name'],
                password=request.DATA['password'],
                email=request.DATA['email'],
                personal_number=request.DATA['personal_number'],
                user_type=request.DATA['user_type'],
                profile_id=request.DATA['profile_id'],
                account_id=request.DATA['account_id']
            )
```

**Edit 1**: **In version 3 (latest) - `request.DATA` has been replaced with `request.data`**:

```
user = dict(
                    full_name=request.data['full_name'],
                    password=request.data['password'],
                    email=request.data['email'],
                    personal_number=request.data['personal_number'],
                    user_type=request.data['user_type'],
                    profile_id=request.data['profile_id'],
                    account_id=request.data['account_id']
                )
```

Comment: `request.DATA` is deprecated in the new versions and replaced by `request.data`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I haven't touched the latest version 3 - using 2.3.13

Answer (score 6):

If the api you are interacting with is a sipmle Django Class Based view, you access the data through `request.body` something like this:

```
class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        field1 = request.body.get('field1')
        field2 = request.body.get('field2')
        ... # processing here
```

In case you are using Django rest framework api, you access the data through `request.data`:

```
field1 = request.data.get('field1')
field2 = request.data.get('field2')
```

**NB:** If you find `request.DATA` used somewhere in Internet that's correct too, but it's only valid for old version of DRF, and it's deprecated in favor of `request.data` in the newer versions.